# CaretIndex inside Textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I am trying to get such effect:
When I click textbox,the caret moves to index 0
example "hello" (|hello)
now when I write something, I want the text to appears before "hello" 
example "hello2hello"

i have already used function such  as:

```
.Select(0,0);

.CurrentIndex=0;

.SelectionStart=0 SelectionLenght=0;
```

those functions only have effect in events `KeyDown` or `TextChanged` events.
Unfortunately those actions don't produce the desired effect.I get mirrored look of what I typed. example(instead of hello I get olleh)
how to change index of the caret after clicking inside the Textbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public string TBName = "";
private void txtResult_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (TBName != ((TextBox)sender).Name)
    {
        ((TextBox)sender).SelectionStart = 0;
        ((TextBox)sender).SelectionLength = 0;
        TBName = ((TextBox)sender).Name;
    }
}
```

You can link it to multiple TextBoxes then as well

Comment: It will obviously be better as well to make sure that `sender` is in fact a TextBox before you do the casting.